# How to edit a 3D matrix using a GUI?

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array, editor

I would like to be able to edit a 3D matrix on a cell by cell basis. I can edit 2D matrices easily using Matlab using the GUI. When I open a 3D matrix in Matlab it is shown sliced up, but the data is not editable. What's a good technique to edit 3D matrices? I don't mind using another software.

Comment: I find it easier to do `A(4,2,3)=pi`. Whats the problem with this?

Comment: Because I am working with fairly large matrices and I need to do lots of editing.

Comment: It seems that you are not using MATLAB correctly.... Are you sure you can not edit your code programatically when using a computer program? Maybe if you share what is your approach to change the values we can share code to do it.  How do you know which values you need to chagne?

Comment: I need to design some 3D shapes like in this image: https://ars.els-cdn.com/content/image/1-s2.0-S003132030700324X-gr2_lrg.gif

Comment: Sounds like you want to use a different program if you're doing a lot of manual editing. There are some small software houses developing niche tools for this sort of thing - Excel is one I've heard of. Just read the data into MATLAB when you've finished manually editing stuff. MATLAB is geared towards programmatic data manipulation.

Comment: I assume those are not random,. And if you need to modify always the same ones, you are better off writing a single piece of code that modifies the matrix for all cases.  However you are not giving enough information for anyone to help.